# Gtkmm 3.0 library for Windows

Tags: windows, gtkmm

Can someone give me a link where i can download a gtkmm 3.0 library for development without need to build it by myself?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://live.gnome.org/gtkmm/MSWindows

That is the best I could find. It stops at 2.8, tough.

http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtkmm-list/2011-April/msg00077.html

That is an email to the gtkmm mailing list from the windows installer developer. It seems that the dev doesn't have much time for it right now (or at least didn't on April 28, 2011).

Not much help, but that seems to be the state of gtk+ and gtkmm on windows right now.

Answer (score 2):

*The original question is old, but I post here for future visitors.*

Apparently the link specified in senshikaze's answer is broken.
Windows installer (for both runtime and development stuff) is available from ftp.gnome.org

[32-bit](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/gtkmm/)

[64-bit](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win64/gtkmm/)

Comment: Helped me anyway. :-)

Comment: This is an old version that includes depricated c++ keywords. Is there an installer for something more recent?

Answer (score 1):

I built the gtkmm binaries over official gtk 3.6.4 binaries.
For 32 bit version you can download the binaries that I created, and there is also the (simple) procedure to create them yourself if you need 64 bit, everything on http://www.giuspen.com/2014/02/build-gtkmm-3-6-0-windows-binaries-on-official-gtk-3-6-4-bundle/

Answer (score 1):

Gtk 3.0 library for windows is at hand from http://www.gtk.org/download/win32.php/

And you could find more optional dependence on http://win32builder.gnome.org/

But Gtkmm 3.0 hasn't have an official release, but some volunteer make it, I find a good one, http://sourceforge.net/projects/tview/files/gtkmm_bin_3_6.7z/download

Answer (score 1):

I created a blog on how to install latest gtkmm on Windows (step by step) here:
http://gtkmm-installation.blogspot.com/

**UPDATE**:
I have just compiled everything with Visual Studio, You can download my gtkmm3 development binaries for Windows x64 from my [GitHub](https://github.com/codekiddy2/Visual-Studio-gtkmm/releases) page, I also made a [wiki](https://github.com/codekiddy2/Visual-Studio-gtkmm/wiki) entry on how to compile everything on your own with Visual Studio.
All of the Visual Studio projects to compile everything can also be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/codekiddy2/Visual-Studio-gtkmm).

Answer (score 0):

You can install it with [vcpkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg).