# Gtkmm and cairomm with visual studio 11 (for the first time)?

Tags: c++, gtk, cairo

I am learning c++ and wish to draw geometry to better enjoy the process and test my scripts.
I searched for a library to draw vectors in c++ and found Cairo came highly recommended on this site. I went ahead and downloaded Gtkmm that comes with Cairomm and installed it. I so far used this aweomse tutorial:

https://live.gnome.org/gtkmm/MSWindows/UsingMSVC

I followed the steps but I think this tutorial might be outdated or there may be an issue with one of the steps on MSVC 2012 with gtkmm-vc100-d-2_4.props (that is perhaps only supported on MSVC 2010).
In general I really want to get started but I am new to this and very confused atm.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the current latest Project property file is not supported with Visual Studio 11 (2012).
I should have known that with the file name being, 'gtkmm-vc100-2_4'.

It works perfectly with VC10 so I reverted to using that for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

I compiled gtkmm3 on Widnows 7 x64 (including cairo and others) for Visual Studio, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256793/gtkmm-3-0-library-for-windows/28112026#28112026)

Answer (score 0):

I have a [CMake based project to build gtkmm](https://github.com/mlt/gtkmm) on top of [MSYS2](https://msys2.github.io) (it used to use [OBS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Build_Service)). It can be used with any version of Visual Studio supported by [CMake](https://chocolatey.org/packages/cmake) as well as plain makefiles and [jom](https://msys2.github.io) makefiles.